# D3 sunburst sequence colors and sunburst arc colors not matching

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am working with a zoomable sunburst in D3 that also has some breadcrumbs. First time working with D3 so I don't know all of the intricacies yet, but I am having trouble getting the colors of the arcs in the sunburst and the breadcrumbs in the sequence to match up. It only ever happens on the leaf nodes too which is weird. I can click on the inner circle and the breadcrumb shows up with the same color, and so on until I click on a leaf node.

Originally I set the color like this `var colors = d3.scale.category10();` and the in the chart options like `color: colors,` When trying to set the colors for the `polygon` for the bread crumb I thought it'd be as simple as this which I had seen from a few examples,

```
entering.append("svg:polygon")
  .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colors(d.name);
  });
```

But this results in the explanation above. So to clarify in the picture below, either the outer arc on the sunburst should be pink, or the lowest bread crumb should be red. (I'm not sure which is correct, probably the former):
[image]
I have a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8L0PAMlGENMvXuqM15Q) I am almost done with, but can't get this part. Also part two kind of, but is it possible to set the color of individual arcs based on a certain value?

**EDIT** Okay well after looking at some more examples, it appears the red on red is okay in the picture for example. So I guess the solution I am looking for is to correct the behavior of the breadcrumbs.